# Regex matching succession of P tags

Tags: php, javascript, regex, pattern-matching, web-scraping

This is a fun little one I've been working on.  I've found many solutions, but none are really the right match.  The goal is this "Match p tags only if there are 3 or more in a row"

So I feel like this should be right, but it's not.

```
<p.*>(.*)<\/p>(?=\s?<p){3,}
```

Basically in my words this says:

- Match a p tag with anything inside the tag
- Match anything until you see a closing P tag
- ONLY match the preceding (above 2 lines) iff followed by

  - a whitespace char (maybe) and then a < p
  - If that occurs 3 or more times

The issue is that this works well in Javascript but not in PHP. PHP says

```
Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 28
```

I've tried different rounds of parens to give it that "nothing to repeat" but that causes false regex.

And yes, this is for web scraping but no I'm doing research not doing evil things.

Any ideas maybe?
thanks!

Comment: I don't actually believe that it "works well."  I can think of more than a few ways to break this using valid HTML.  Moreover, I don't think you've tested this code fully, because `(?= )` construct is a zero-width assertion.  If you match it once you can match as many times as you like.  `$ echo "testabba" | perl -ne 'if (/test(?=abba){3,}/) { print "blah\n"; }'` `blah`  Additionally, you have greedy matches that should be non-greedy.  Especially if you intend to use a capturing group.

Comment: I agree, I haven't done any valid checks on it, because I'm just trying to the concept group to work. I was replacing the *> with <p[^>]+ in another version.  I appreciate the feedback but it doesn't help me figure out how to match a set of p tags.

Comment: You haven't really given enough information to make a regex, is this intended on just returning a true or false?  Or did you want the data within the `<p>` tags as well?  Just the first one?  Or all 3?  Because your code currently will match any number of `<p>` tags and pull the data from the last tag (no matter what it is) before the last `</p>`to the last `</p>`, which I do not think is intended behavior.

Comment: Yea, you're right about that.  The goal is given an HTML page that I know has a succession of P tags on it. I want those P tags.  So if there are 5 P tags in a row, I want not just those 5, but the entire succession of P tags. There might be 20 P tags one after another (with maybe some whitespace) and thats what I'm trying to match and return.

Comment: can you please review the answers you have been given and either accept the one that helped you most/solved your problem or point out why none of the answers solved your problem. thanks

Comment: I'm close to being able to update this. I'll post the answer any day now. I figured out the regex solution but I need to let it finish with the beta testers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A state machine XML parser (a SAX parser) seems most appropriate to me. Here is an example:

```
class StateHelper {

    function __construct($filename) {
        $this->p_count = 0;
        $this->p_elements = array();
        $this->in_p = FALSE;
        $this->minimum_in_succession = 2;
        $this->successive_element_data = array();
        $parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_set_element_handler($parser, array($this, 'start_element'), NULL);
        xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, array($this, 'character_data'));

        $fp = fopen($filename, 'r')
            or die ("Cannot open $filename");

        while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
            xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp)) or 
                die(sprintf('XML ERROR: %s at line %d',
                xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
                xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
        }
        xml_parser_free($parser);
        $this->start_element(NULL, "end", NULL);
    }

    function start_element($parser, $element_name, $element_attrs) {
        if ($element_name == 'P') {
            $this->p_count += 1;
            $this->in_p = TRUE;
        } else {
            if ($this->p_count >= $this->minimum_in_succession) {
                $this->successive_element_data[] = $this->p_elements;
            }
            $this->p_elements = array();
            $this->p_count = 0;
            $this->in_p = FALSE;
        }
    }

    function character_data($parser, $data) {
        if ($this->in_p && strlen(trim($data))) {
            $this->p_elements[] = $data;
        }
    }
}

$parseState = new StateHelper("example.html");
print_r($parseState->successive_element_data);
```

**example.html***

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Foo1</p>
        <p>Foo2</p>
        <p>Foo3</p>
        <div>
            <p>Bar1</p>
            <p>Bar2</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Baz1</p>
                <p>Baz2</p>
                <p>Baz3</p>
                <p>Baz4</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Foo1
            [1] => Foo2
            [2] => Foo3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Baz1
            [1] => Baz2
            [2] => Baz3
            [3] => Baz4
        )

)
```

Comment: So you're basically rendering the page as XML, then looping through tags looking for the multiple P pattern. Do I have that about right? What kind of speed are we looking at to parse the page with XML?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is likely giving you that error because your zero-width assertion is useless to repeat, both perl and javascript do not warn you of that.

If you match it once you can match as many times as you like, because it doesn't actually consume anything.

Depending on what you intend to do you might be able to get away with a regex.  But if you need to actually know about your HTML in any fashion you'd be best off with using an HTML parsing library.

What is it that you need to do?

Comment: The goal is to find a succession of p tags. So if there are 5 p tags in a row, i want that whole group of p tags, not just the 5, but that entire succession.

Comment: More globally than that, I'm trying to find the article text on some news article page.

Comment: also to note, even if this were DOM, and I had jQuery it wouldn't help find the pattern.  I don't know any class or id info about the parent div, so I can't actually find it with DOM. The only pattern I know is that its 1 p tag after another, which probably some whitespace in between

Comment: Then your best bet is actually to anchor it using the surrounding HTML.  Generally, those pages will all have the article text in a particular class and will always be preceded and followed by predictable HTML sequences that you can search for.  For instance, CNN.com precedes article text with an HTML comment that says `<!--startclickprintinclude-->`

Comment: But in order to get the container, I still need to have matched that there is a succession of P tags inside.  Sure CNN has a match with a comment, but i'm working with 100s of sites that don't follow a comment pattern.  I'm still looking for other patterns, but I feel like 3 p tags in a row can be solved with regex

Comment: Dude, it's in a <div> with the class name "articlecontents"  Just use DOM to pull it

Comment: Dude, I'm doing this on 100s of pages, they don't all share any pattern of containers.  Anyway, I think I got a solution, it's not quite there, but it's as close as i've gotten. `(<p[^>]*>.*<\/p>\s*){3,}`

Comment: It compresses all the P tags in one match, but I can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) instead? The expression then would simply be:

```
//p[name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'p' and name(following-sibling::*[2]) = 'p']
```

The query will find all `p` anywhere in the document which have two `p` immediately following.

**Example ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JkorGg)):**

```
$html = <<< HTML
<div>
    <p>lore</p>
    <p>ipsum</p>
    <p>dolor</p>
    <br/>
    <p>sit</p>
    <p>amet</p> 
</div>
HTML;
```

We only want to find the first element in this snippet. The code would then be:

```
$query = "//p[
    name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'p' and 
    name(following-sibling::*[2]) = 'p'
]";

print_r(xpath_match_all($query, $html));
```

**Output:**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => <p>lore</p>
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => lore
    )
)
```

The resulting array contains the outerHTML and innerHTML for that query.

Of course you don't have to use the [`xpath_match_all`](https://gist.github.com/1358174) function. It's just a convenience utility. For alternatives, see [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. But it brings 2 questions to mind.  This won't be able to get all the P tags right? It will be missing the last 2, because the 2nd last doesn't have 2 p tags following and neither does the last one.

Also, its rendering the page as DOM, do you think that's performant?  If i'm doing 20 pages, each has to render as DOM, in my mind, it can't even touch how fast if you just did string matching. Maybe I'm wrong on this.

Comment: @Sean The XPath will get all P elements having two direct P siblings. However, it's trivial to get those two siblings with DOM. As for the performance aspect: if you have a performance requirement, measure the code and see if it performs well enough. If you don't have a performance requirement, go for better readability, which (imo) is this solution.